# How to iterate a node in Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a simple database in Firebase like this:
[image]

The following code currently reads a resource fill and render each item read to a RecyclerView.

```
public class kos_putra extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<Kost> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    KostAdapter mAdapter;
    DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

    public kos_putra() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kos_putra, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new KostAdapter(mList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        fillData();
        return view;
    }


    private void fillData() {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        String[] arJudul = resources.getStringArray(R.array.places);
        String[] arDeskripsi = resources.getStringArray(R.array.place_desc);
        String[] arLokasi = resources.getStringArray(R.array.place_locations);
        TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.places_picture);
        Drawable[] arFoto = new Drawable[a.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arFoto.length; i++) {
            BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) a.getDrawable(i);
            RoundedBitmapDrawable rbd =
                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bd.getBitmap());
            rbd.setCircular(true);
            arFoto[i] = rbd;
        }
        a.recycle();

        for (int i = 0; i < arJudul.length; i++) {
            mList.add(new Kost(arJudul[i], arDeskripsi[i], arLokasi[i], arFoto[i]));
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void fetchDataFromFirebase(){
        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("kos_putra");
    }
}
```

Now instead of reading from a file, I want to read from Firebase instead. How do I iterate each node under **kos_putra**? In the picture below, there are 4 objects. Logically, I'm thinking of getting the data count first, then do a for-loop. Still not clear how to do it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate in each node, do this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("kos_putra");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
  for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String deskripsi=data.child("deskripsi").getValue().toString();
       String nama=data.child("nama").getValue().toString();
    }
  }
      @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
   });
```

Here your datasnapshot is on `kos_putra`, add a listener on that location will iterate on all nodes(1,2,3,4) and with the for loop it will get the values that are inside all nodes also.

Comment: Hi Peter. Sorry, my app didn't displayed the Firebase content... turns out I forgot to adjust rule. Should be ".read": true. Anway, yeah it works fine :)

Comment: yes , read and write:true until you authenticate users you can change it then, and okay great! happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

myRef.child("users").child(firebaseAuth.uid.toString()).addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

```
                    try {
                        var td=snapshot.value as HashMap<String,Any>
                        for(key in td.keys){
                            var userInfo=td[key] as String
                            if(key.equals("imageUrl")){
                                Picasso.get().load(userInfo).into(myView.imageProfilePhoto);
                            }else if(key.equals("name")){
                                myView.username.setText(userInfo)
                            }

                        }


                    }catch (ex:Exception){}
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }
            })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
fun iterateFirebaseNodes() {
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val ref = database.reference.child("your-node-path")
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                // This gives you the value of the child node
                val childData = childSnapshot.value 
                println(childData)
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            println("Failed to read value: ${error.toException()}")
        }
    })`
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76916975/edit) your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**